# How to copy multiple files from a different directory using cp?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to copy multiple files from a specific directory once I am in  another directory. To clarify I want to do the following, at once (one command):

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file1 .
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file2 .
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file3 .
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file4 .
```

I can't use  `cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/* .`   because in `dir2` there are `n` files `(n>4)`

By the way, I'm using `bash`.

Thanks.

Comment: cp -t Directory source is an option
This can be used to copy all/selected files from one dir to another....

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file[1234] .
```

or (in Bash)

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file{1..4} .
```

If the file names are non-contiguous, you can use

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/{march,april,may} .
```

Comment: thanks
actually in the real case the name of the files are completely different.
 `cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/[march april may] .`
will not work

Comment: Why don't you tell us the real case then?

Comment: @ziulfer: OK, that one is also possible with the brace syntax.

Comment: Thank you once again. This brace syntax has been very useful to me. However, one stuff that I really miss from the default, file-by-file, cp command is the possibility to have auto-completion. Is there a possibility to have this with the brace syntax?

Comment: in case someone runs in to this, it is important there are no spaces between commas and filenames in the `{alpha.a,beta.b,gamma.g,delta.d}` type list

Answer (score 5):

If all the files you want to copy are in the pattern of `file{number}{othertext}`, you could use something like:

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file[0-9]* .
```

Note that this will copy `file5`, but it will also copy `file0abc`.

If you would like to copy ONLY those four files (and not the {othertext} ones), you can use:

```
cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file[1-4] .
```

Note that while this *looks* like part of a regular expression, it is not.

Comment: thanks actually in the real case the name of the files are completely different. `cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/[march april may]  .` will not work

Comment: But that wasn't your question.

Comment: Also want to mention that `cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/F* .` works. This is for the case where only the starting letter in the filenames is the same. And only those files starting with `F` are desired to be copied

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
 cp ../dir5/dir4/dir3/dir2/file{1..4}
```

Comment: Only works in bash.  OP didn't specify what shell he's using.